# Scheduled task causes OutOfMemoryError (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, cron, jvm

Application works fine until scheduled task starts in back end. This task updates posts from cloud database and if where is a change it rewrites existing post. after it updates about 400 - 500 posts , application crashes H2 database and gives an error : Exception in thread "File Watcher" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

My sheduled task

```
 @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 15 ? * SUN")
  public void updateAllWeekly() {
    log.debug(
        "<< UPDATE ALL >> CRON IS STARTED. The time is now {}", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    postService.updateAll();
  }
```

updateAll method

```
  public void updateAll() {

    try {

      Long startId = 0L;

      do {
        startId = updateFrom(startId);
      } while (startId > 0);

    } catch (FeignException ex) {
      log.debug("CALL ERROR", ex.contentUTF8());
      return;
    }
  }
```

updateFrom method

```
public Long updateFrom(Long startId) {

    Long lastd = startId;

    try {
      List<Post> posts = cloud.pullPostsFromId(startId)
      int postSize = posts.size();

      if (postSize > 0) {
        lastd = posts.get(postSize - 1).getId();
      } else {
        startId = -1L;
        return startId;
      }

      for (Post post : posts) {

        updatePost(post);
      }

    } catch (FeignException ex) {
      log.debug("CALL ERROR");
    }

    return lastd + 1;
  }
```

updatePost method finds Post by id (post.getId) sets changed parameters ( if any ) and save it back to database

Full error :

```
Exception in thread "File Watcher" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3821)
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.newString(StringLatin1.java:767)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1907)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1875)
    at java.base/java.io.File.getName(File.java:459)
    at java.base/java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(UnixFileSystem.java:262)
    at java.base/java.io.File.isFile(File.java:886)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FolderSnapshot.collectFiles(FolderSnapshot.java:69)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FolderSnapshot.collectFiles(FolderSnapshot.java:67)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FolderSnapshot.collectFiles(FolderSnapshot.java:67)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FolderSnapshot.collectFiles(FolderSnapshot.java:67)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FolderSnapshot.collectFiles(FolderSnapshot.java:67)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FolderSnapshot.<init>(FolderSnapshot.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FileSystemWatcher$Watcher.getCurrentSnapshots(FileSystemWatcher.java:277)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FileSystemWatcher$Watcher.scan(FileSystemWatcher.java:251)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FileSystemWatcher$Watcher.run(FileSystemWatcher.java:236)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Comment: Maybe using an in-memory database (H2) isn't the best choice for large datasets... Use a proper database instead. Also this seems to appear in Spring Boot Devtools, maybe you should stop using those and just re-start the application when needed.

Comment: i have about 20 000 + posts and after i grab all of once  , my backend updates them every week. so big amount of objects can cause this error?

Comment: Please look at your stacktrace. It is due to devtools keeping track of files, stop using devtools. Also H2 is an **in-memory** database so eventually that will also fill up your memory.

Comment: oh i did not think devtools could be an issue despite it being in stacktrace. Thanks for suggestions